# nebula.release plugin attempts to push root project to bintray

Tags: bintray, netflix-nebula-plugins

I am having trouble getting my library deployed to bintray and synced to Maven Central. It appears that I'm using the plugin wrong, but I cannot figure out how. I've tried many things including using the kotlin gradle dsl, extracting logic out of the root build.gradle, renaming my submodules, only specifying nebula.release on the subprojects (apparently you can't do that), and on and on.

My project is set up like this

```
axon-kotlin
  gradle
    publishing.gradle
    ...
  samples
    build.gradle
    ...
  axon-kotlin-test
    build.gradle
    ...
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'axon-kotlin'
include 'axon-kotlin-test', 'samples'
```

axon-kotlin/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.dokka" version "0.9.17"
    id 'nebula.kotlin' version '1.2.50'
    id 'nebula.maven-publish' version '8.0.0'
    id 'nebula.info' version '3.7.1'
    id "nebula.source-jar" version "8.0.0"
    id 'nebula.nebula-bintray-publishing' version '3.5.5'
    id 'nebula.release' version '6.3.5'
    id "org.ajoberstar.github-pages" version "1.7.2"
    id 'org.jbake.site' version '1.2.0'
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.15.1'
}

group 'com.tylerthrailkill'
description "Extensions to the Axon Framework"

allprojects {
    group 'com.tylerthrailkill'
    description "Extensions to the Axon Framework"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
def axonVersion = '3.2.2'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "nebula.kotlin"
    apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.dokka"
    apply plugin: "nebula.kotlin"

    dependencies {
        compile group: "org.axonframework", name: "axon-core", version: axonVersion
        compile group: "org.axonframework", name: "axon-test", version: axonVersion
        compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'

        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3'
        testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
        testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"

        testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.2.41"
        testCompile group: "org.axonframework", name: "axon-core", version: axonVersion
        testCompile group: "org.axonframework", name: "axon-test", version: axonVersion
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        dependsOn 'cleanTest'
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
    }

}

buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    publishAlways()
}
```

axon-kotlin-test/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("nebula.maven-publish")
    id("nebula.info")
    id("nebula.source-jar")
    id("nebula.javadoc-jar")
    id("nebula.nebula-bintray-publishing")
    id("nebula.release")
    id("org.ajoberstar.github-pages")
    id("nebula.contacts-pom") version("2.2.2")
}

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/dokka.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/publishing.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/site.gradle"

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.11.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    implementation("org.axonframework:axon-core")
    implementation("org.axonframework:axon-test")
    implementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3")
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testCompile("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0")

    testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.2.41")
    testImplementation("org.axonframework:axon-core")
    testImplementation("org.axonframework:axon-test")
}
```

samples/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":axon-kotlin-test"))
    //    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.11.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    implementation("org.axonframework:axon-core")
    implementation("org.axonframework:axon-test")
    implementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3")
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testCompile("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0")

    testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.2.41")
    testImplementation("org.axonframework:axon-core")
    testImplementation("org.axonframework:axon-test")
}
```

publishing.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.release'
apply plugin: 'nebula.contacts-base'
apply plugin: 'contacts-pom'
apply plugin: 'nebula.maven-publish'

contacts {
    "myemail@gmail.com" {
        moniker = "Tyler Thrailkill"
        role("owner")
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        nebula(MavenPublication) {
            pom.licenses {
                license {
                    name = 'The MIT License'
                    url = 'https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    distribution = 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = findProperty('bintrayUser') ?: System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = findProperty('bintrayKey') ?: System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')
    override = true

    pkg {
        userOrg = 'snowe'
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'Axon-Kotlin'
        desc = "Extensions to the Axon Framework "
        licenses = ['MIT']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/snowe2010/axon-kotlin.git'
        websiteUrl = 'https://github.com/snowe2010/${project.name}'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/snowe2010/${project.name}/issues'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/snowe2010/${project.name}.git'
        labels = ['axon', 'kotlin']
        version {
            gpg {
                sign = true
                passphrase = findProperty('gpgPassphrase') ?: System.getenv('GPG_PASSPHRASE')
            }
        }
    }
    dryRun = false
    publish = true
}
```

Problem is I get this large error when trying to deploy using nebula release:

```
> Task :axon-kotlin:publishNebulaPublicationToMavenLocal
Task ':axon-kotlin:publishNebulaPublicationToMavenLocal' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Publishing to maven local repository
:axon-kotlin:publishNebulaPublicationToMavenLocal (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.183 secs.
:axon-kotlin:bintrayUpload (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :axon-kotlin:bintrayUpload
Task ':axon-kotlin:bintrayUpload' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Gradle Bintray Plugin version: 1.8.4
Version 'snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6' does not exist. Attempting to create it...
Created version '0.1.6'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6-sources.jar...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6-sources.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6-javadoc.jar...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6-javadoc.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6.jar...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6.pom...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/snowe/maven/Axon-Kotlin/0.1.6/com/tylerthrailkill/axon-kotlin/0.1.6/axon-kotlin-0.1.6.pom'.
:axon-kotlin:bintrayUpload (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 2.549 secs.
:bintrayUpload (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :bintrayUpload FAILED
Task ':bintrayUpload' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Gradle Bintray Plugin version: 1.8.4
Package 'axon-kotlin' does not exist. Attempting to create it...
:bintrayUpload (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.358 secs.
:bintrayPublish (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :bintrayPublish FAILED
Task ':bintrayPublish' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
:bintrayPublish (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.044 secs.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create package 'nebula/gradle-plugins/axon-kotlin': HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [message:forbidden]

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not create package 'nebula/gradle-plugins/axon-kotlin': HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [message:forbidden]
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask$_checkAndCreatePackage_closure8$_closure19.doCall(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:291)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:434)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:383)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask.checkAndCreatePackage(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:274)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask.bintrayUpload(BintrayUploadTask.groovy:236)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 31 more

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bintrayPublish'.
> Could not sign version 'unspecified': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Package 'axon-kotlin' was not found]

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bintrayPublish'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not sign version 'unspecified': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Package 'axon-kotlin' was not found]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayPublishTask$_gpgSignVersion_closure1$_closure5.doCall(BintrayPublishTask.groovy:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:434)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:383)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayPublishTask.gpgSignVersion(BintrayPublishTask.groovy:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayPublishTask.signPublishAndSync(BintrayPublishTask.groovy:53)
        at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayPublishTask.taskAction(BintrayPublishTask.groovy:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 34 more
```

This is the command I use to release: 
`./gradlew -Prelease.useLastTag=true final --stacktrace --info`

I feel like I'm probably doing something wrong, but I've tried just about every thing under the sun. Here are all of the things I've tried in git commit form https://github.com/snowe2010/axon-kotlin/commits/master